# Worklight SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated

Tags: ssl, ibm-mobilefirst

This is post is in continuation of the below post in Worklight:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=470764

As suggested by Idan in the last comment, there is no `JAVA_HOME` environment variable set as of now on the Linux machine.
The problem is even if I set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, I am not sure which jdk path to add as there are multiple instances present on the Linux machine.

Please suggest me as to which jdk path to pick.

Thanks

Comment: What are your existing JDK paths? Why is there more than installation of JDK? Have you tried the suggestion to use that of JDK6?

Comment: Sorry, posting after a bit late but thanks Idan, after setting the JAVA_HOME env variable the problem was resolved.

Comment: Would really love to accept the above comment as answer but accepted answer tick mark is showing up there. Instead its showing in the below comment. Any suggestions how to accept it as answer

Comment: Maybe you need to be logged in...

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Worklight system requirements depending on what version you are using, and what set up you need. However, if I remember correctly, I think you are cool using Oracle JDK 1.7 or IBM JDK 1.6.